# How to send jar file output to a json file using python

Tags: python, json, file, jar

I have jar file when executed will print out the output on the terminal, Im not sure how can i pass the jar file output as a json file.

The code below just print the jar file output on the terminal

```
subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', '/home/myfolder/collect.jar'])
```

I'm thinking of below but no idea to start with...

```
with open('collect.json', 'w') as fp:
    xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Hope someone could advise further. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the output from .jar execution in python codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510360/how-to-get-the-output-from-jar-execution-in-python-codes)

Comment: I have tried before I post my questions...still failed anyway thanks for your advise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. If you look at the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) you can see that check_output runs a command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess

command = "java -jar /home/myfolder/collect.jar"

def runCommand(q):
    commandOutput = subprocess.check_output(command.split()).decode("utf-8")
    q.put(commandOutput)

q = mp.Queue()
commandProcess = mp.Process(target=runCommand, args=(q, ))
commandProcess.start()
output = q.get()
print(output)
with open('collect.json', w) as fp: 
    fp.write(output)
```

Didn't run the code, but should work.

Comment: Hi...Im getting error ImportError: No module named mutiprocessing.my pip list does have mutiprocess install

Comment: Sorry...typo error of multiprocessing..i run again the code... anyway...the code run but the json file empty...no data on it...

Comment: @chenoi Try the code above again, i fotgot to actually write the file (see fp.write(output))

Comment: It works...thank you so much.... i spot the missing pieces earlier...thank you for your attention and support...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
with open('collect.json','w') as fp :
  subprocess.Popen('java -jar .//home/myfolder/collect.jar',stdout=fp).wait()
```

for further information, see this question [How to get the output from .jar execution in python codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510360/how-to-get-the-output-from-jar-execution-in-python-codes)

I hope this helped.

Comment: hi....this getting error raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: I add [] as below subprocess.Popen(['java -jar .//home/myfolder/collect.jar'],stdout=fp).wait()